# How to open existing local pod in xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

Is it possible to open a local pod in xcode. Not by adding to a Xcode project and then edit it ?

I want to open a existing pod file on my hardrive.

So far, tried like this on terminal
1) cd my directory where the pod file is
2) open Podfile -a Xcode

It says xcode does not support opening folders without project or workspace

PS there are 3 files inside my local pod file
1) LICENSE.txt
1) mainfolder - contains classes folder

The answers below just let me open or create a blank pod file
My issue is that local pod file do not have .xcodeproj file. Just swift and obj C file in it. Hope to open it in xcode for making changes in pod or is it not possible ?

Link i followed to created the pod - [Create Pod](http://raptureinvenice.com/developing-a-local-cocoapod-alongside-your-ios-app/)

Answer (score 7):

Open Terminal

Move to your project directory

```
$ cd "your_project_location"
```

Now run below command, this will **open file in Xcode**

```
open -a XCode Podfile
```

If you want ot open in **some other text editor**, then try below command

```
open -e Podfile
```

It will open podfile in your default text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in terminal

```
touch podfile
```

and then

```
open -e podfile
```

Answer (score 1):

open Terminal
go to your project path like:  /Volumes/Work/Projects/..

```
 $ cd "your_project_location"
 $ open -a Xcode Podfile
```