# Use of undeclared type 'UIWindowScene'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am developing with Xcode.

An error appears at line 156 of BaseNotificationBanner.swift file of cocoapod.

**BaseNotificationBanner.swift Line 156**

```
.map { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
```

How can I fix it?

**BaseNotificationBanner.swift**

```
/// The main window of the application which banner views are placed on
private let appWindow: UIWindow? = {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .first { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .map { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
            .map { $0?.windows.first } ?? UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window ?? nil
    }

    return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window ?? nil
}()
```

Comment: why you are not providing error?

Comment: That code is only valid in iOS 13. But I would not use such code in iOS 13. There is no "app window" in iOS 13 because you can have multiple scenes each with their own scene and window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIWindowScene` is introduced in iOS 13, it seems like you are on older Xcode version, so you either have to update to Xcode 11 or specify an older version of NotificationBanner pod like so: -

`pod 'NotificationBannerSwift', '2.5.0'`

Comment: @user1090751 check this: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188090/how-to-open-existing-local-pod-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode 11 can solve this problem. 
I have installed Xcode 10 and Xcode 11. I realized that If I use Xcode 10 to run the project which is created by Xcode 11. It will show the error `Use of undeclared type 'UIWindowScene'`.